# Android GUI update at runtime

Tags: android, user-interface, runtime

I have a native method which is called from Java layer and is called
successfully. 
The native method sends two integer values to the java layer at different times, and these values are received successfully in the java layer (to and fro data transfer is successful.). 
My problem is:In android  GUI I have take these two values and update the textbox(textview) with the data received at the java layer. The data can be seen in the log if i print it(system.out.println(..).... or Log.e(..)).  but the 'textbox.settext(..) doesn't update the textbox, even though it is printed in string format.

How can i update these values in the Android GUI Layer ?
I tried using thread, handler and postinvalidate() methods, but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone tell me on how to update the gui on runtime ? Any trick to update or refresh ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you use "myTextView.setText("new");" but you are not in the ui-thread.
try

```
runOnUiThread(new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            //update your view here
        }
    });
```

furthermore take a look at:
[Android update UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683164/android-update-ui)